# Renaming attributes names if one is deleted before submit with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, rename

I have a list of inputs generated by jQuery :

```
<input type='text' name='field["+ j++ +"]' />
<input type='file' name='field["+ j++ +"]' />
<textarea name='field["+ j++ +"]' value='' />
<textarea name='field["+ j++ +"]' value=''/>
```

j++ increment when the user add a new input field and it finally look like this :

```
<input type='text' name='field[0]' />
<input type='file' name='field[1]' />
<textarea name='field[2]' value='' />
<textarea name='field[3]' value=''/>
```

Now the user has the possibility to delete a field with a button, example : if I deleted the field[2] it results this :

```
<input type='text' name='field[0]' />
<input type='file' name='field[1]' />
<textarea name='field[3]' value=''/>
```

The problem is that the incremented fields are no more suitable later because instead of a list like 0,1,2,3... I have 0,1,3...

I just want to change the number attribute of fields after the one which has been deleted to fit with others incremented fields

**Another thing : the user can drag and drop fields to change the order. So if 1 field is deleted the field right after must take its number place and so on**

The code to delete a field :

```
$("#deletebtn").live("click", function(){
  $(this).parent("li").remove();
});
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a common class name to all elements using the ordering:

```
<input type='text' name='field[0]' class='dynamic-order' />
<input type='file' name='field[1]' class='dynamic-order' />
<textarea name='field[2]' value='' class='dynamic-order' />
<textarea name='field[3]' value='' class='dynamic-order' />
```

Then after an element is removed, iterate over the fields and set new index:

```
$("#deletebtn").live("click", function(){
  $(this).parent("li").remove();
  $( ".dynamic-order" ).each(
    function( index ) {
    this.name = "field["+index+"]";
    }
  );
});
```

edit: I found some problems with your jsfiddle, here is the fixed version:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZKFHH/1/

For some reason the names don't always show the most recent value, you have to check the property for it.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I've tried that and if I remove a field the indexes don't changes, example : I click delete on field[2] and the others don't change their indexes. Any idea?

Comment: No idea unless you link to the page where it is used :)

Comment: Ah sorry it's local :/ Maybe it's because the inputs are generated by jQuery

Comment: Well I've tried with this.name = "field[test]"; and it seems that the only name attribute which change is the input right before the one I've deleted. The others keeps their names

Comment: Thanks for the update and your help! It works if I remove an input and add another (the index follow the one before) but if I remove the input [1] between 2 others it's still like [0][2][3] instead of [0][1][2]. Any idea ?

Comment: Yes, it's because they are not updating in your firebug/web inspector. Just close the inspector and click inspect element again and you should have the most recent values. The values are internally correct.

Comment: Oh exactly it works! My fault (previous version of jQuery) It works perfeclty many thanks and sorry to annoy you!

Answer (score 1):

You may omit the index, use only `field[]`

Comment: Thanks for answer, I can't remove the index because I need it in my code later

Comment: What's the reason, it doesn't look like there is a special relationship between the index and the field as long as you like to reassign the index.

Comment: Yeah, it's because after the submit I do some php manipulation to make a relationship between a rank array and the inputs so the inputs must have an index to match with the rank

Comment: The inputs will have an index after the submit, they will be indexed automatic starting with 0

Comment: Dr.Molle is correct, if you are just submitting these to php there is no need to have any numbering in the fields.

Comment: Yes but the index after submit will be 0 1 2 3 or here I can drag an drop and remove fields so the index could be 3 0 2 1 and this is important to match with my order array later

Answer (score 0):

First of all: if you using that name forms for posting it with php (or asp) as array you do need to enumarete the name of the inputs, you can use just name="field[]".

If you want just the names to be in that way, then give to your input a class:

```
<input type='text' class="input" name='field[0]' />
<input type='file' class="input" name='field[1]' />
<textarea class="input" name='field[2]' value='' />
<textarea class="input" name='field[3]' value=''/>
```

Then with jquery, every time the user change order/removes an input just execute this function:

```
function re_order(class)
{
  $('.'+class).each(function(index,element){
    this.name='field['+index']';
  });
}
```

where class is the class given to the inputs.

Comment: class is a future reserved keyword, just pointing it out :P https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words#section_1